# When does an Activity go into paused without being stopped after?

Tags: android

I wanted to understand when an activity can be in the paused state, so onPause is called, without going into the stopped state (onStop) after. Pretty much like onPause() -> onResume() without passing by onStop -> onRestart -> onStart

Comment: I believe this lifecycle flow is observed when the user has multiple apps open at the same time, side by side, with focus in the other application.

Answer (score 1):

onResume method is called when the activity is in focus meaning the user can interact with the visible activity on the screen. onPause is called when the activity loses focus i.e. the user cannot interact with the activity but the activity is still partially visible to the user. onPause and onResume can be seen in action when interacting with a dialog box.

[onResume to onPause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAuCB.png)

When a dialog box appears in front of the ongoing activity, the activity loses focus because the dialog has to gain the user's focus. The activity lifecycle goes from onResume to onPause state. When the user has responded to the dialog and the dialog dismisses then the activity again gains its focus. This time the activity lifecycle goes from onPause to onResume.

onStop is called after onPause only when the android OS detects that the ongoing activity has a chance to get destroyed. This usually happens when activity goes in the background (in recent apps stack). Android system automatically destroys apps from the recent apps stack to free up memory space if those apps are not opened by the user for a while.